# CallableStatement and VARCHAR limitations

Tags: java, sql-server

I'm executing a stored procedure SQL SERVER from JAVA, in this way:

```
StringBuilder sqlSP = new StringBuilder();
sqlSP.append("{ call MY_PROCEDURE (?) }");

//Connection parameters configured
CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall(sqlSP.toString());
cs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
cs.execute();
String xml = cs.getString(1);
logger.info(xml.length());
```

This procedure in SQLSERVER return a VARCHAR(max), almost 49k characters, but JAva get only 4k characters.

How can i fix this ?

Comment: are you sure you are returning 49K characters? By `VARCHAR(MAX)` you should be able to see 8000 on your Java code.

Comment: I've used your code and I can see 8000 as the length

Comment: I fixed the problem passing this outputparameter as a ResultSet.

Comment: Please provide an EDIT on your question to provide what you've did, so that the others can leverage over this information!